# analysis services cell data - permitting access to all members

Tags: ssas, mdx

Just a little question for you...

I'm currently trying to implement a role structure for an analysis services cube. To enable writeback support for a specific role I followed the Microsoft "Enabling and Securing Data Entry with Analysis Services Writeback" guide. Now I want to alllow write acces to all cells (measures) of the cube.

It works fine if I select a specific cell with the following MDX-statements:

```
Measures.CurrentMember IS Measures.[Sales Amount Quota]
```

But I don't find the right statement to allow access to all cells. Regarding to this [site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174904) that should be an easy thing, but they didn't post a MDX-statement there. With a blank expression access is denied and without selecting anything in the cell data tab page it is denied too.

Has anyone an idea?

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need an expression that returns a True result. Try

```
Measures.CurrentMember IS Measures.CurrentMember
```